# ¿Por que me sale ese error? [Error] expected primary-expression before '[' token (simulador de banco con 5 clientes)

Tags: c

No está completo el programa, pero lo que quiero hacer es que recorra cada cliente de la estructura para ver si la cuenta que pone como `entrada` existe. Los datos de los clientes ya están registrados (deben estar ya registrados), solamente tiene que poner la cuenta, pero me aparece:

```
[Error] expected primary-expression before '[' token
```

Donde esta el `if` dentro del `for`, lo que quiero que haga es saber si es igual a algunas de las cuentas de los clientes y ponga un 1 en la `n` si no un 0, pero no se que expresión primaria tengo que poner o quitar. Repito, no esta terminado el programa ya que con ese error no puedo continuar.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void re();
void de();
void tr();

int numero,cuenta,n;
char menu;

struct cliente{
    char nombre[30];
    double cel;
    int cuenta;
    int saldo;
}

cliente1={"monica",9981265845,1248,5000},
cliente2={"andrea",9981254585,9568,2500},
cliente3={"daniel",9981232545,6326,6000},
cliente4={"luis",9982160758,2256,3500},
cliente5={"pedro",9982458515,5612,7800};    

int main(){
    do{
        printf("Menu");
        printf("1:Retiro\n 2:Deposito\n 3:Transferencia\n 4:salir del sistema");
        scanf("%d",&numero);

        switch(numero){
            case 1: 
                re();
                break;
            case 2:
                de();
                break;
            case 3:
                tr();
                break;
            case 4:
            return 0;
                break;
        }

        printf("volver al menu: (si=s no=n)");
        scanf("%s",&menu);
    }while(menu=='s');

    return 0;
}

void re(){
    do{
        printf("numero de cuenta:");
        scanf("%d",&cuenta);

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            if(cuenta== cliente[i].cuenta){
                n=1;
            }else{
                n=0;
            }
        }

        if(n==0){
            printf("no existe");
        }
    }while(n==0);
}
```

Comment: Hola Andrea. El lenguaje está hecho en C, no C#. Cambialo cuando puedas

Comment: No se si ha sido un error tipográfico al transcribir, pero tu método `re` creo que tiene un `}` de más. Es algo que se ve muy claro cuando identas correctamente el código.

Comment: Arreglando el problema de que `cliente` no está definido en `if(cuenta== cliente[i].cuenta){` y que hay llamadas a las funciones `de()` y `tr()` (que no están definidas), no obtengo ningún otro mensaje de error al compilar. ¿Podrías compartir el mensaje de error completo incluyendo el número de línea en el que se produce ese error? Es posible que se esté generando en otra parte diferente que no has mostrado aquí.

Answer (score 2):

Te he corregido el código. Tenías un error a la hora de definir la estructura y posterior inicialización de los datos. Para que sea correcto, tienes que declarar la estructura y, luego, crear un array de esa estructura con los datos.

Luego ya podrás interactuar con esa variable en tu programa.

Además, sé que has dicho que el programa no estaba terminado, pero no te olvides de declarar los métodos "de()" y "tr()", aunque estén vacíos, en el switch los nombras, así que si no los defines te da error de compilación.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void re();
void de();
void tr();

int numero,cuenta,n;
char menu;

typedef struct{
    char nombre[30];
    double cel;
    int cuenta;
    int saldo;
} cliente;

cliente clientes[5] = {{"monica",9981265845,1248,5000}, 
                       {"andrea",9981254585,9568,2500}, 
                       {"daniel",9981232545,6326,6000}, 
                       {"luis",9982160758,2256,3500}, 
                       {"pedro",9982458515,5612,7800}};

int main(){
    do{
        printf("Menu\n");
        printf(" 1:Retiro\n 2:Deposito\n 3:Transferencia\n 4:salir del sistema");
        scanf("%d",&numero);

        switch(numero){
            case 1: 
                re();
                break;
            case 2:
                de();
                break;
            case 3:
                tr();
                break;
            case 4:
            return 0;
                break;
        }

        printf("volver al menu: (si=s no=n)");
        scanf("%s",&menu);
    }while(menu=='s');

    return 0;
}

void re(){
    do{
        printf("numero de cuenta:");
        scanf("%d",&cuenta);

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            if(cuenta == clientes[i].cuenta){
                n=1;
            }else{
                n=0;
            }
        }

        if(n==0){
            printf("no existe");
        }
    }while(n==0);
}


void de(){
}

void tr(){
}
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Con esto ya puedes seguir.